# VS Code "Better handling for Unicode combining characters": not

Tags: visual-studio, unicode, combining-marks

In the change documented [enter link description here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40) entitled "Better handling for Unicode combining characters", it says VS Code "made improvements around handling of Unicode combining characters and we treat such sequences as atomic characters (in cursor movement, editing operations, or in block cursor rendering)".  My problem is that that's exactly what I *don't* want to do; I want the cursor and editing operations to treat the base character and any combining characters as separate characters, so I can edit them individually.

Am I correct that there's no way to revert to the previous behavior--no toggle?  (I could of course install the earlier version of VS Code, but that's a losing proposition, as there are likely to be many later changes that I'll want.)  Do I need to submit a request, or am I overlooking s.t.?

BTW, I know about Unicode normalization forms; once normalized to NFC, the cursor would pretty much have to behave like it does now.  But so long as the base text is NFD, I'd like to be able to edit combining chars separately (especially nice when I need to edit stacked diacritics).

Comment: I think someone already reported that: [Left delete behavior in some languages is changed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84897), [VS Code deletes whole clusters with backspace now and does not work with Keyman](https://github.com/keymanapp/keyman/issues/2315)

Comment: Yeah, I know it changed, I was hoping there was a toggle to turn off the change.  But apparently not.